# How to rip an audio CD in .wav format to .wav lossless but add track info

Tags: sound, cd, copy, wav

The most recommended Ubuntu audio CD ripper is Sound Juicer.  However, Sound Juicer doesn't copy .WAV into .WAV.  It copies to .OGG format and I worry that it is a lossy compressive copy.

The WAV files on my CD come up in file browser as "Track 1.wav", "Track 2.wav" and so on. Is there a similar program to Sound Juicer which gets the metadata and renames the .WAV file, but which does a straight bit-for-bit copy of the .WAV file in a lossless way?

Comment: You should rip to a compressed lossless format, i.e., flac. About half the size of wav, all bits preserved. Like ogg, the format supports metadata.

Comment: Thanks I will rip to FLAC.  Does that work in my car?  Or do I need to Sound Converter the FLAC to WAV?

Comment: That, I can not know.